# Sharing exFAT drive via Netatalk, can't create directories

Tags: archlinux, file-sharing, file-server, netatalk

I set up my Pi 3 to serve an external drive with Netatalk to access it from my Macbook. Works well, but I can't create directories with Finder. Creating files, renaming, deleting files and directories work, but not creating them. Do you know whats wrong?

```
> ls -l /mnt
drwxrwxrwx 1 dikti dikti 131072 Nov  3 11:14 BM

> cat /etc/afp.conf
[Global]
hosts allow = 192.168.178.0/16

[BM]
path = /mnt/BM
valid users = dikti
; also tried what follows below:
file perm = 0666
directory perm = 0777
rwlist = dikti
```

Edit: I use Archlinux for ARM, so Netatalk is current:

```
> uname -a
Linux alarmpi 4.9.59-1-ARCH #1 SMP Sun Oct 29 20:24:30 UTC 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
> netatalk -v
netatalk 3.1.11 - Netatalk AFP server service controller daemon
```

Comment: `netatalk` sharing is defined in `/etc/netatalk/AppleVolumes.default` (the normal default is HOME directory only).

Comment: Was correct with 2.x, they changed to afp.conf with 3.0 (http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/3.0/ReleaseNotes-3.0.html)

Comment: Did you compile 3.0? If so you should specify in your question; the supported version is 2.2.5.

Comment: sorry, forgot mentioning I'm not using Debian, see Edit

Comment: I'm using netatalk on a RPi 3B running raspbian stretch with no issues. I do have settings in `/etc/netatalk/AppleVolumes.default` which read `~/ "$u's home directory"` for home directories and `/data/backup/TimeMachine/MacBookAir "MacBook Air Backup" allow:myname cnidscheme:cdb options:usedots,upriv` for TimeMachine backups. Interestingly, on my debian desktop machine, also running `netatalk` serving home directories and TimeMachine volumes, all of the configuration is done in `/etc/netatalk/afpd.conf`. I'm not sure why I did that, but both are working.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve this problem by adding:
`unix priv = no`

to the `[share]` section in `/etc/netatalk/afp.conf`.

Inspirational source:
http://www.gattis.org/Work-and-Tech/operating-systems-and-applications/backup/time-machine-ubuntu

Situational details:

```
Client: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 
Server: Raspberry Pi model 4B running Raspbian 10.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your macbook terminal do:

```
cd (drive name)
```

than try

```
mk (directory name)
```

If it doesnt work try using `sudo` before the command.

Comment: > cd /Volumes/BM; mkdir foo results in `mkdir: foo: Permission denied`

Comment: did you try doing sudo before the command? if so it look as if the drive is locking you fron creating a directory

Comment: did, permission denied either way

Comment: not sure then, my basic knowledge hasnt gotten me far.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using netatalk at all. [Apple has deprecated AFP](http://appleinsider.com/articles/13/06/11/apple-shifts-from-afp-file-sharing-to-smb2-in-os-x-109-mavericks) in favor of SMB. So samba is the way to go.
As of OS X 10.11 Yosemite I also experience issues with other AppleTalk devices. On my old Lacie EthernetDisk mini I could not even connect using AFP any more.

Comment: I know, but Time Machine won't backup to a samba share without crude hacks, while netatalk has direct support for it. Also, AFP is much faster in my experience listing directories, time till a movie starts etc.

Comment: I think you have misleading information. Maybe you can point out your sources. Using Time Machine over Network always leads to the creation of a Sparse Image. This is how TimeCapsule or expensive Enterprise Synology NAS provide Time Machine backups over the network. This is independent of AFP or SMB. To run Time Machine natively you will need the backup volume to be HFS+ and have a client that is able to take advantage of it. So only using another computer with macOS / OS X / MacOS X is capable of doing this.

Comment: (But even here I am not 100% certain and have to check at home. Perhaps it does a sparse image anyway.)

Comment: I'm backing up to my debian server running netatalk configured to provide a 2 TB TimeMachine volume on my 4 TB ext4-formatted drive. I've been using it for years, and have successfully restored my iMac from it more than once (thanks to a failing iMac). There may be other ways of configuring TimeMachine with Linux, but this has been by far the easiest approach I've found.

Comment: @kwasmich - Have to agree as the Files app on iOS only supports SMD v2.0 or above but SAMBA is significantly more pain to get running and is slower.